# Android Connecting to Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am creating an android application in android studio and I am using SQLite as the local database. I am using MySQL database as the application server. I want to be able to pull the data from MySQL into Android Studio to access it and also sync the local SQLite database and the MySQL database.
I do not want to use Web services and php files to connect MySQL, I would like to use JDBC instead, so My question is:
can I use JDBC to this purpose and how?

Comment: Is this an application for the general public to use? If so, giving them direct access to your MySQL database is a super bad idea.

Comment: I cannot agree with this enough.